# Secure WebSocket and PHP

Tags: php, ssl, websocket

I have a Windows 2012 R2 Server with IIS and PHP (5.5.12).

I'm trying to make a (secure) WebSocket server. So, I made this :

```
$host = 'ssl://127.0.0.1'; // host
$port = '8080'; // port

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

socket_listen($socket);
```

Everything works fine when I connect with ws:// and I receive the correct headers :

```
GET /server.php HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: site.url:8080
Origin: https://site.url
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: MwqZ0uVuheQaS3ks7EJARQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-d
eflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
```

But when I try to connect using wss:// ... I receive something weird :

```
▬♥☺ ø☺  ù♥☺¶P↓ÚðÙ±s÷╠Þ´▲è♣ÖaN?uüEg´¯§òñÞ=¿§  *└
└       └‼└¶└↕└└◄ 3 2 E 9 8 ê ▬ / A 5 ä
 ♣ ♦☺  D   ↑ ▬  ‼         site.url  ☺ ☺
 ♠ ↨ ↑ ↓ ♂ ☻☺  #  3t   ♣ ♣☺
```

And I can't do the handshake ...

Is there anything I did wrong ?

Thank you for your help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: yes, you get ssl encrypted data. That's normal. You need to first decrypt the ssl to read data here.

Comment: You might consider an alternative server language for this, nodejs i believe is becoming popular for web sockets.  PHP processes can still be invoked via... processes

Answer (score 0):

Try using [stream sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) instead and [setting the stream context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php). Also, you might want to use tls:// instead of ssl://